# Is it possible to enter Taiwan without a return ticket?

Tags: visas, taiwan, proof-of-onward-travel

Will Taiwan let me in if I show up with a one-way ticket only?

My nationality is visa exempt and I can stay 90 days in Taiwan with no problem. My plan is to get to Taiwan, hang out for a bit (anywhere from 1 week to 3 months), and then keep traveling to other countries in southeast Asia. Of course I didn't plan anything besides the one way flight and the hotel for the first two nights. I was wondering if anyone has experience getting to Taiwan without an already scheduled flight to exit the country. I know that the US would not like that at all for instance...

Comment: In many cases immigration will not require you to have onward tickets if you can prove you can afford to buy them. But _the airline_ may require you to have an onward ticket in order to board you. In these cases a cheap flight or even ferry to anywhere will suffice.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [Bureau of Consular Affairs, Ministry of Foreign Affairs, Republic of China (Taiwan)](http://www.boca.gov.tw/content?mp=2&CuItem=1443), the requirements for visa-exempt travel to Taiwan include :

> 2.a confirmed return air/sea ticket or an air/sea ticket and a visa for the next destination, and a confirmed seat reservation for
>   departure.

Timatic (the system used by most my airlines to check visa requirements) also states that :

> Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.

Which means that it's likely that the airline involved wouldn't allow you to actually board the plane to Taiwan without an onward ticket.

Answer (score -2):

I've flown to Taiwan many times and the only airline that requires return tickets is jetstar, so just avoid them and you're good, it's a horrible company anyways

Comment: I'm confused. The question is about what _Taiwan_ requires. And in what sense does Jetstar "require" a return ticket? Are you saying they won't let somebody board a flight to Taiwan unless they have a return ticket? An onward ticket? What if they're a Taiwanese resident?

Comment: You probably just need an outbound ticket from Taiwan (any destination). Many airlines companies won't let you on a flight bound to the US if you don't have a "tourist visa" and an outbound flight already booked. This does not apply for residents of course. I ended up going to Taiwan and I got asked a couple of questions boarding the second leg of the flight in Tokyo. No "formal checks".

Comment: No need to dislike my comment, just because you’re confused. I constantly fly between Japan, Taiwan and China, entered Taiwan 5 times last year alone, and the only company, that ever required proof of onward travel, was Jetstar. So to answer the question in a way that should be less confusing to you: Yes, you can enter Taiwan with a one way ticket, but not if you fly with Jetstar, then you can’t even get to Taiwan. Now, get over your arrogance and stop downvoting useful information to future travelers.

Comment: both of you! ;) https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/